# Routing to components

Tags: routes, sapui5

I am trying to write/support a suite of SAPUI5 components.

I have a component that displays a list of overview items. I also have a component that displays a list of detail items. I would like to connect these two components via routing.

The document "[Working with Nested Components](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/2c/66fb3eb775426087401117cfa6a94e/content.htm)" gives tantalizing hints that it is possible. But there is no documentation on how to actually accomplish this.

I have added the described routes to both components. But I do not know how to actually link the components so that they are aware of each other.

I tried to update the overview items so that a click will create a new component, but I don't know what parameter to give the `placeAt()` function. (The `controlId` I used in the routing doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not how exactly you are trying achieve. The best solution would be Master-detail pattern.
[Read more here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8ed9339f3a99418e82a02f0fb4b5d6b9.html)

Creating new component on each click of the overview items is not a good idea. You should route to detail page which knows what are you dealing with and fetches more information if needed to show.

Let me know if you have trouble.